# Missing CRLF in final records causing a problem in reading in data sets

Tags: r

I have two data sets containing rows of data where the last row is missing a  CRLF. I am having to add it to the files in order to read them in. Is there a way I can read in without modifying these files?

One of the final records looks like this:

```
surface NewYork Ave.             1259 1290 no final carriage return 
                                                at end of record
```

Warning message:

```
In readLines(file, n = thisblock) : incomplete final line found on 
                                     roadways.dat'
```

Thanks. MM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I managed to have reproduced your problem is when I use a win unicode file `encoding = "UCS-2LE"`. A couple of ways to go about the problem, and a **warning** for you to test it if it produces the desired output. In most cases it is a warning which you can suppress using available switches.

```r
# set the warning FALSE (Assuming it is just a warning with no effect)
data <- readLines(con <- file("your_file", encoding = "UCS-2LE"), warn = FALSE, n=-1)
# Or see if other alternative encoding can solve your problem 
A <- readLines(con <- file("your_file", encoding = "UTF-8"), n=-1)
```